# Can I get same data using POST rote that I got using GET route

Tags: laravel-routing, laravel-10, laravel-controller

I have two routes in my Web.php,

```
Route::get('/employees', [ApiController::class, 'employees'])->name('employees');
Route::post('/employeesPost', [ApiController::class, 'employees'])->name('employees.post');
```

This is Controller Code, where I am fetching data from database, and sand it in JSON format:

```
public function employees() {
    try {
        //code...
        $employees = Employees::all();
        $data = [];
        $usingCollection = new EmployeeCollection($employees);

        // format data
        foreach ($employees as $key => $employee) {
          $data[] = [
                 'id' => $employee->id,
                 'name' => $employee->name,
                 ];
        }

       // make response array
          $response = [
                'message' => 'successful get data',
                'code' => 200,
                'Employees' => $usingCollection,
            ];

          return response()->json($response, 200);
       } catch (\Throwable $th) {
          $response = [
               'message' => 'Something went Wrong',
               'code' => 404,
               'Employees' => $th->getMessage(),
           ];

          return response()->json($response, 404);
    }
}
```

My GET Route is working great, but I want to get same data using POST route, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same API in the `Get` and `Post` method.

```
Route::get('/employees', [ApiController::class, 'employees'])->name('employees');
Route::post('/employees', [ApiController::class, 'employees'])->name('employees.post');
```

This code handles both GET and POST requests to the /employees endpoint.

Comment: I have tried That, it is not working for me , it Showing error
The GET method is not supported for route api/employees. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Please let me know what exact errors you have more. I don't understand your situation.